# Hibernate Session Factory is expensive-to-create

Tags: hibernate, sessionfactory, hibernate-session

I read everywhere that Hibernate SessionFactory is expensive-to-create operation. But there is no clarity on what is the expensive part ? Can anyone please explain.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/architecture/Architecture.html#:%7E:text=A%20SessionFactory%20is%20very%20expensive,%2C%20transaction%20system%20integrations%2C%20etc.): "The SessionFactory maintains services that Hibernate uses across all Session(s) such as second level caches, connection pools, transaction system integrations, etc."

I guess that creating all this services must be an expensive task.